# Map Parent/Child Interface Properties using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following interface and DTO used in a standard hierarchical structure:

```
public interface IPageView {
    IPageView Parent { get; set; }
    ICollection<IPageView> Children { get; set; }
}
```

this is implemented using the following concrete class:

```
public class PageView : IPageView {
    IPageView Parent { get; set; }
    ICollection<IPageView> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I've omitted other properties and constructor for brevity.  I'm using Automapper to map from my `Page` EF POCO Entity to the interface DTO with the following:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Page, IPageView>().As<PageView>();
```

When AutoMapper tries to create the map, I get the following exception:

> The following property on Pipeline.CMS.Contracts.UI.IPageView cannot be mapped: 
>       Pages
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Pipeline.CMS.Contracts.UI.IPageView.
>   Context:
>       Mapping to property Pages from Model.Page to Interfaces.IPageView
>       Mapping to property Pages from System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Model.Page,Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Interfaces.IPageView, Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>       Mapping from type ModelPage to Interfaces.IPageView
>   Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.

Obviously this is because AutoMapper cannot map the IPageView as it has not been mapped yet!

My question is how I can resolve this? I don't mind specifying a concrete class in the AutoMapper configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the above code is OK and the problem isn't related to the hierarchy, BUT a map needs to be created between the original source object and the object in the `As` method.  For the above, it would be:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Page, PageView>(); // Additional line here needed
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Page, IPageView>().As<PageView>();
```